# Angular Form Reset getting Error "Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges"

Tags: angular, observable

I am resetting form after value is saved successfully.! I am calling service method to pass data to API.

```
this.customerService.saveSupplier({ customerId: Context.customerId, supplier: supplier }).subscribe(res => {
      this.pageReset();
})

pageReset() {
    this.isSubmitted = false;
    this.loadData();
    this.isPanelShow = false;
    this.form.reset({ supplierId: "" });
}
```

My service is working successfully. but after calling it I am getting in console.
[image]

I am not destroying component nor changing my route after successfully save. I've check some links suggest to unsubscribe the observable but still it is giving same error.

Comment: If you are using isPanelShow to hide html element using ngIf, this may cause the problem as ngIf removes that portion of the DOM.

Comment: @NTP - Yes, form is getting hide after data is saved and appears again on show button

Comment: but, I tried to reset form before hiding the it. but it shows same error

Comment: can you comment this.isPanelShow = false; line to see if the error is caused because of that line or not.

Comment: yes, after commenting it is working properly.

Comment: it may not be the most elegant solution but you can try to use timeout to execute this.isPanelShow = false; after few ms.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.isPanelShow = false
```

is causing the error as you are using this variable inside a ngIf directive to hide your elements. ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM therefore when isPanelShow is false

```
this.form.reset({ supplierId: "" });
```

causes the “Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges” error.